# selecting multi elements within a HTML div

Tags: html, css

I have a Div with an ID (termsAndConditions-sectionB) - and inside that Div there are blocks of headers and paragraphs (h4, p). I want to make all the text / elements inside the Div #termsAndConditions-sectionB to be Justified (text-align: justify;).

I know that in order to do this to all of the Div's elements, I have to do it as follows:

```
#termsAndConditions-sectionB h4, #termsAndConditions-sectionB p {   
    text-align: justify;
}
```

My questions is, is there another way to select all of it's elements and justify them using something as simple as this?

```
 #termsAndConditions-sectionB { 
     text-align: justify;
 }
```

I have tried it, and it did not work, I have searched Google for some alternatives, but just couldn't find a clear answer, I may have used the wrong keywords - I am new to this, so any help would be much appreciated.

*If you are wondering why I am asking this: is because I want to make my CSS much easier to read, organized and as less as possible.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use asterix

```
#termsAndConditions-sectionB * { 
     text-align: justify;
 }
```

(This will be applied to all descendents)

Comment: @Loai There's nothing bad about it. You can always override this rule if you like. Lets say you want the spans to be left aligned, you can use `#termsAndConditions-sectionB span { text-align:left; }`

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer! It worked - I was just afraid that it may not work on old browsers - that was my concern.

Comment: There is a performance cost. The CSS engine sees a hit on the rightmost part of the selector for every element, and has to go up the DOM to qualify it. Selectors with * on the right should be avoided in pages with deep DOM hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wildcard.

```
#termsAndConditions-sectionB * { 
 text-align: justify;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a bad practice, but it may work if there is no other simple solutions.

```
#termsAndConditions-sectionB { 
  text-align: justify !important;
}
```